# How to obtain original sanskrit literature on Samaveda Sandhyavandana?

Tags: sama-veda, sandhyavandanam

I have the sandhya vandana (nitya karma) in my mother tongue, where the sanskrit words are phonetically translated into my language. I perform this once daily.

I noticed similar copies in other languages too.

So there must be a original base version in Sanskrit, which everyone is copying from?

Could anyone help me find a place where I can get/buy the Sanskrit version?
I am learning Sanskrit now, so I want to be able to refer the source myself.

Comment: @ram Thanks a lot. The english version is very detailed. But when I clicked on the  Sanskrit link, it is only 2 pages. I do understand the english has wider reach and it makes sense. Do you know if there is any way I can buy the full sanskrit version?

Comment: Thank you very much. Much appreciated.

Comment: FYI, you have to learn all ritual & mantra from a guru, only then use book to refresh memory. i'm going to delete my comments since it's only for those initiated already.

Comment: @ram Yes, I was initiated when 11 years old. I am trying to reattach myself to my roots.